# Wordpress Get the CURRENT Category from Single Post, Multiple Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I've got a Custom Post Type of **Home Plan** and a Custom Taxonomy of **Community**.

The same **Home Plan** appears in *multiple* different **Communities**.

Permalinks have been set, and now I'm trying to find the *current* **Community** from which I'm viewing the **Home Plan**.

Because the **Home Plan** appears in multiple **Communities**, the following example links all take you to the *same* **Home Plan** as intended:

- domain.com/community-name-1/plan-name
- domain.com/community-name-2/plan-name
- domain.com/community-name-3/plan-name

In order to display the relevant information based on the **Community**, I'm attempting to find a way to determine the *current* **Community**.

In my single-home-plans.php file, I've printed get_query_object(); and get_the_terms(); but I haven't found anything useful.

A possible workaround would be to pass a $_GET value, but at this point that's an absolute last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `query_var` is set to `true` in the taxonomy, you can detect which category is currently being viewed by using `$wp_query` (global),

`$wp_query->query_vars['the_taxonomy_name'];`

Run `var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);` to view the full array of all query information.

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$home_plan_community = $wp_query->query_vars['community'];
echo $home_plan_community; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No such thing as current taxonomy, when you on single page. You can only check from which taxonomy user go to this page. You can do this by checking $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your url are as simple as what you've provided, this will probably do,

```
// Get the Current  URL path
$url =  "{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}";

// Convert URL path string to array
$e = explode('/', $url ); // You can dump this to verify which is the taxonomy slug

// Get all taxonomy slug assigned on this post
$taxonomy = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'your_taxonomy');
$tax_names = '';
foreach( $taxonomy as $tax ) {
    $tax_names .= '&nbsp;'. $tax->slug;
}
// check if 2nd array which is the current taxonomy exist on list of taxonomy assigned to post
if( isset( $e[1] ) && strpos($tax_names, $e[1]) !== false ) {
    // Get Term Name by slug
    $term = get_term_by('slug', $e[1], 'your_taxonomy');
    _e( $term->name);
} else {
    _e($e[1]. ' is not a valid taxonomy for this post');
}
```